# Need help to correctly adjust the width/height when using GridView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, alignment

Using the GridView.builder I have layed a series of containers. When a given container is tapped, another container overlayed via the Stack widget will appear in the exact same position and will animate to the center of the screen.

(each container will actually display a different image and the end-effect is that of the image animating in scale to the center when tapped).

I use global key to get the position of the tapped widget and the provider package. This works when the GridView.builder is scaled at screen size.

**However - when I constrain the GridView.builder to say 0.80 of screen width**, I can't work out how to adjust the x (or y) position of the overlayed container to exactly overlay the same position to that of the tapped container container.

I have tried to offsetting the position by the same ratio etc, and I can't get it right. Would really  appreciate some help!

I suspect the issue lies here:

```
return RelativeRectTween(
      begin: RelativeRect.fromSize(
          Rect.fromLTWH(
              notifier.widgetsPosition.dx.abs(), // how to correctly adjust this x value???
              notifier.widgetsPosition.dy.abs(),
              notifier.widgetsSize.width,
              notifier.widgetsSize.height
          ),
```

Here is the full code for context. I have tried to strip out as much as I can. I have also set the end animation to the same as the start animation below, so the issue is clearer to test.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GridNotifier()),


      ],
      child: MaterialApp(

          home: GridSelector()),
    );
  }
}




class GridSelector extends StatefulWidget {
  const GridSelector({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GridSelectorState createState() => _GridSelectorState();
}

class _GridSelectorState extends State<GridSelector>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  // this works if the size multiplier is set at 1.0 = but I can't get to work at a lower value
  final double _sizeMultiplier = 0.80;

  bool _tapped = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 9000), vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (Provider.of<GridNotifier>(context).tapped == true) {
      _tapped = true;
      _controller.forward();
      setState(() {});
    }

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  Size size = Size(0, 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * _sizeMultiplier,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              final _biggest = constraints.biggest;
              print(
                  'constraint width  ${_biggest.width} and constraint height is ${_biggest.height}');
              return Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3),
                        itemCount: 20,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: Box(
                                index: index,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Consumer<GridNotifier>(
                      builder: (_, notifier, __) {
                        return PositionedTransition(
                          rect: buildRelativeRectTween(notifier, _biggest).animate(
                            CurvedAnimation(
                                parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
                          ),
                          child: _tapped
                              ? GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _tapped = false;
                              _controller.reset();
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              // width: notifier.widgetsSize.width,
                              // height: notifier.widgetsSize.height,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                      notifier.widgetsIndex.toString())),
                            ),
                          )
                              : Container(),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  RelativeRectTween buildRelativeRectTween(
      GridNotifier notifier, Size _biggest) {
    return RelativeRectTween(
      begin: RelativeRect.fromSize(
          Rect.fromLTWH(
              notifier.widgetsPosition.dx.abs(), // adjust this x value
              notifier.widgetsPosition.dy.abs(),
              notifier.widgetsSize.width,
              notifier.widgetsSize.height
          ),
          _biggest),
      end: RelativeRect.fromSize(
          Rect.fromLTWH(
              notifier.widgetsPosition.dx.abs(),
              notifier.widgetsPosition.dy.abs(),
              notifier.widgetsSize.width,
              notifier.widgetsSize.height

          ),
          _biggest),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatelessWidget {
  Box({
    required this.index,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final _key = GlobalKey();

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      key: _key,
      onTap: () {
        final _offset = getWidgetsPosition(_key);
        final _size = getWidgetsSize(_key);

        context
            .read<GridNotifier>()
            .setPosition(offset: _offset, size: _size, index: index);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
      ),
    );
  }


}

class GridNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  Offset widgetsPosition = Offset(0, 0);
  Size widgetsSize = Size(1, 1);
  int widgetsIndex = 0;
  bool tapped = false;

  setPosition({required Offset offset, required Size size, int index = 0}) {
    widgetsPosition = offset;
    widgetsSize = size;
    widgetsIndex = index;
    tapped = true;
    print('widgets position is $offset and size is $size');

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Offset getWidgetsPosition(GlobalKey key) {
  if (key.currentContext != null) {
    RenderBox _renderBox =
    key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    return _renderBox.globalToLocal(Offset(0, 0));
  } else
    return Offset(0, 0);
}

Size getWidgetsSize(GlobalKey key) {
  if (key.currentContext != null) {
    final _renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    return _renderBox.size;
  } else
    return Size(0, 0);
}

[![Example of issue][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRHsZ.png
```